# Matlab: how to save my struct to a CSV file?

Tags: matlab

I have a variable that I got from Matlab's load() function:

```
K>> data

data = 

  struct with fields:

  dset: [1×1 struct]
```

I tried the following to save the contents to disk:

```
csvwrite("dddd.txt", data)
csvwrite("dddd.txt", data.dset)
```

Error message: Check for missing argument or incorrect argument data type in call to function 'real'.

Comment: You’re not giving any information about what this struct looks like, what is inside it. JSON as suggested below seems the only possible answer, as it is generic. If you need CSV, you need to show what is inside the struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are working with a structure you probably want to serialize it to a format like JSON, and then write it to a file:

```
json_data = jsonencode(data.dset);
writematrix(json_data, "dddd.csv");
```

Comment: I upvoted, seems a reasonable solution for OP’s issue. But I can imagine someone thinking “JSON is not CSV, this isn’t answering the question”. I also wonder why OP didn’t upvote, but accepted. I think people here need to upvote more.

Answer (score 2):

One can use `struct2table` and `writetable` to quickly export to a CSV file. There are some limitations on the form of the structure when using `struct2table`. Here is a simple example:

```
myStruct(1) = struct('Double',pi,'String',"string value",'Boolean',true);
myStruct(2) = struct('Double',exp(1),'String',"Stack Overflow",'Boolean',false);
myStruct(3) = struct('Double',42,'String',"Matlab",'Boolean',true);

myTable = struct2table(myStruct);

writetable(myTable,'C:\Temp\output.csv','delimiter',',');
```

output.csv:

```
Double,String,Boolean
3.14159265358979,string value,1
2.71828182845905,Stack Overflow,0
42,Matlab,1
```

If the structure is more complicated, then one probably is better off using JSON encoding as suggested by Paolo.