# Converting a complicated data structure (nested and with different data types) from MATLAB to CSV

Tags: matlab, data-structures, nested

I have a 'def.mat' file which has a 'data' with 1*42 struct inside and has 8 Fields. Inside of each (aside from only 2 Fields out of 8) there are nested structures as well, and all are 1 * 1 struct, double and cell data types.
I want to convert them into CSV files to later on read it in Python.
It would be great if you help me to tackle this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matlab: how to save my struct to a CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64211171/matlab-how-to-save-my-struct-to-a-csv-file)

Comment: No actually it's more complicated than that. in nested structs also are other nested structs with different data types. I have tried jasonencode and dosn't help.

Comment: Why doesn’t `jasonencode` help? JSON seems a good encoding for your data.

Comment: Each nested struct or field can be exported to its own CSV or JSON file for better organization and clarity. Storing everything in a single file may lead to loss of structure and make it more challenging to interpret the data. In my application, CSV files work better.

Answer (score 0):

After days working on this, I came to the solution that if your data structure contains nested structs with different data types, it may not be suitable to store everything in a single CSV or JSON file. In that case, it's best to organize the data into separate files based on the structure or fields.

After looping over each field in the struct, I needed to handle nested structures 'recursively'. The code then checks the data type of the field value. If the field value is a struct, the code enters another loop to handle nested structures. The code then checks the data type of the nested field value. If it is a struct, the code enters another loop to handle further nesting. The code checks the data type of the nested struct field value. If it is numeric (a single value), the code writes the value to a CSV file using `writematrix()`. If it is an array of values, the code converts it to a cell array using `num2cell()` and writes it to a CSV file using `writecell()`.
If the nested struct field value is a cell array, it is directly written to a CSV file using `writecell()`.

Comment: I don’t think you can call that a CSV file…